# How to change log message color in Kur?

Tags: python, deep-learning

If you read a lot of Kur's log messages on console, and if you found your eyes are shy away from the colors like below: 
[image: shining]

Could we change the color of logging messages?

Answer (score 0):

I can change the color among 8 different colors provided in `kur/kur/utils/logcolor.py`

```
import logging

# Get the eight standard colors.
BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE = range(8)

# ANSI escape sequences for colored outputs.
RESET_SEQ = "\033[0m"
COLOR_SEQ = "\033[1;{}m"
BOLD_SEQ = "\033[1m"

# Color codes for each log-level.
COLORS = {
    'DEBUG': BLUE,
    'INFO': WHITE,      # change to BLACK, for example
    'WARNING': YELLOW,  
    'ERROR': RED,
    'CRITICAL': RED
}
```

However, I tried to rename the 8 colors into different colors but it seems not working on other color names.

If anyone knows how to change color WHITE to GRAY or any other color, please let me know. Thanks.